# Expand notification instead of open app

Tags: android, push-notification

I have a notification with 2 extra actions, for each action I've set an activity to be launched upon user touch, but sometimes the notification shows collapsed.
The notification can actually be expanded by dragging it, but this is not intuitive for the user.

There is any way to set the collapsed notification to expand itself on touch?